# Storm Trident 'merge' function that preserves time order

Tags: apache-storm, trident

Say I have two streams:

```
Stream 1: [1,3],[2,4]
Stream 2: [2,5],[3,2]
```

A regular merge would produce a Stream 3, like this:

```
[1,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,2]
```

I would like to merge the stream whilst preserving the order in which the
tuple was emitted, so if `[2,5]` was emitted at time 1, `[1,3]` was emitted at
time 2, `[3,2]` at time 3 and `[2,4]` at time 4, the resulting stream would
be:

```
[2,5],[1,3],[3,2],[2,4]
```

Is there anyway way to do this and, if so, how? Some sample code would be
appreciated as I'm a complete Trident rookie who has recently been thrust
into a Trident based project.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Eli

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an external data storage using trident persistent. Sorted set of redis should serve your purpose, I guess.

**MORE INFO**

If you go through this https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial, you can get how to use memcache as the store for words count.

Similarly, you can write a stream backup on Redis (if you are not familiar with redis try out,
http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set). I think redis sorted set will serve as a purpose for your case.

If you want a persistent storage for your data, you can think of using other NOSQL solution like mongo and then you can always easily index your final data on your time. That will easily provide the sort functionality you want. And what not someone has already written a mongo trident, https://github.com/sjoerdmulder/trident-mongodb.

Let me know if you are still confused and about what.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, with a bit of sample code. I am a real rookie. Thanks very much

Comment: I've currently got it working using MySQL as my external data source. Eventually I'll have to use something a bit more sophisticated, but it will do for now. Thanks very much for your help.